# How can i select the option of ul list item with selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

How can i select item of ul list with selenium with C# in web page . Currently i have web page i can access the other control by id of that but this select control are not able to work with me what i have tried

[image]

what i have tried is

```
           IWebElement elements = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ant-select-dropdown-menu"));
            SelectElement ses = new SelectElement(elements);
            ses.SelectByText("Web Project");
```

**The Error Message is**

no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".ant-select-dropdown-menu"}

Answer (score 0):

This drop down is not built up using `Select and option tag (HTML)`, so we can not use `Select class from selenium`, we will have to `click` on this drop down first and then store all options in a list and then iterate through the list and using if clause (if desired text is found) click on it.

Click on the drop down like this :

```
IWebElement elements = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("ul[class*='ant-select-dropdown-menu']"));
elements.Click();
```

and then use `FindElements`

```
IList<IWebElement> selectElements  = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("ul[class*='ant-select-dropdown-menu'] li"));
    For(WebElement ele : selectElements){
      if(ele.GetText() == "Desktop project")    
          ele.Click();
}
```

Comment: Still giving me error of no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".ant-select-dropdown-menu"}

Comment: for this line `driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("ul[class*='ant-select-dropdown-menu']"));` ?

Comment: yes on this line
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("ul[class*='ant-select-dropdown-menu']"));

Comment: Go to Chrome - > Dev too (F12) and then Elements section and then do CTRL + F and then paste  `ul[class*='ant-select-dropdown-menu']`, Do you see any entry ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank You I Solve my problem with this

```
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("selectid"));
            element.Click();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            var slctOption = 
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[contains(text(),'Desktop 
            Project')]"));
            slctOption.Click();
```

Comment: Where is `selectid`  in shared HTML ?

Comment: I added the id of select input tag then call it.